# Calculate average before and after a Date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data frame, I'm trying to calculate Average of "Price" column before and after Rate change, not considering in the average calculation the value of the Month when Rate changed. for example for Client "XY Ltd" rate Increased on Aug. so, Average of Price before rate change would be (5+6)/2
Average price after rate changed would be (-3-5)/2

below is the code I tried, but I don't know how to exclude the values of the Month when rate changed.
Also, I'm trying to create another column with the Subtraction of "Average after rate change" - "average before rate changed"

```
df['New Column'] =  df.groupby(['Client', 'Rate'])['Price'].transform('mean')
```

| Date | Client | Rate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01 | XY Ltd | 1.50 | 5 |
| 2022-07-01 | XY Ltd | 1.50 | 6 |
| 2022-08-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | 10 |
| 2022-09-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | -3 |
| 2022-10-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | -5 |
| 2022-06-01 | ZZ Inc | 1.60 | 3 |
| 2022-07-01 | ZZ Inc | 1.60 | 4 |
| 2022-08-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | 12 |
| 2022-09-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | -4 |
| 2022-10-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | -6 |

desired output

| Date | Client | Rate | Price | New Colum | New column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01 | XY Ltd | 1.50 | 5 | 5.5 | -9.5 |
| 2022-07-01 | XY Ltd | 1.50 | 6 | 5.5 | -9.5 |
| 2022-08-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | 10 | 0.0 | -9.5 |
| 2022-09-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | -3 | -4.0 | -9.5 |
| 2022-10-01 | XY Ltd | 3.00 | -5 | -4.0 | -9.5 |
| 2022-06-01 | ZZ Inc | 1.60 | 3 | 3.5 | -8.5 |
| 2022-07-01 | ZZ Inc | 1.60 | 4 | 3.5 | -8.5 |
| 2022-08-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | 12 | 0.0 | -8.5 |
| 2022-09-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | -4 | -5.0 | -8.5 |
| 2022-10-01 | ZZ Inc | 4.00 | -6 | -5.0 | -8.5 |

Another Sample Data with Prod ID

| Date | Client | Prod ID | Rate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-30 | LL Inco | 71 | 0 | -29 |
| 2021-11-30 | LL Inco | 73 | 1.6 | 889 |
| 2021-11-30 | LL Inco | 74 | 1.6 | 754 |
| 2021-11-30 | LL Inco | 75 | 1.6 | 2608 |
| 2021-12-31 | LL Inco | 71 | 0 | -31 |
| 2021-12-31 | LL Inco | 73 | 1.6 | 916 |
| 2021-12-31 | LL Inco | 74 | 1.6 | 777 |
| 2021-12-31 | LL Inco | 75 | 1.6 | 2688 |

Comment: Your calculation for `XY Ltd` when `Rate = 3.00` ignored the 10. Why is that?

Comment: I have to do an Analysis before and after of the Month when Rate change. @ Code Different

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're asking:

```py
df = df.join(df.groupby('Client')['Rate'].agg(['first']), on='Client')
df['rate_change'] = (df.Rate != df['first']) & (df.Rate.shift() == df['first'])
df['cs'] = df.groupby('Client')['rate_change'].cumsum() * (2 * ~df.rate_change - 1)
df2 = df.groupby(['Client','cs'])['Price'].mean().reset_index(level='cs')
df = df.join(df2[df2.cs == 0].rename(columns={'Price':'pre_change_avg'}).drop(columns='cs'),on='Client')
df = df.join(df2[df2.cs == 1].rename(columns={'Price':'post_change_avg'}).drop(columns='cs'),on='Client')
df['New Column'] = np.where((df.Rate == df['first']), df.pre_change_avg, np.where(df.rate_change, 0, df.post_change_avg))
df['New Column 2'] = df.post_change_avg - df.pre_change_avg
df = df.drop(columns=['first','rate_change','cs','pre_change_avg','post_change_avg'])
```

Output:

```
        Date  Client  Rate  Price  New Column  New Column 2
0 2022-06-01  XY Ltd   1.5      5         5.5          -9.5
1 2022-07-01  XY Ltd   1.5      6         5.5          -9.5
2 2022-08-01  XY Ltd   3.0     10         0.0          -9.5
3 2022-09-01  XY Ltd   3.0     -3        -4.0          -9.5
4 2022-10-01  XY Ltd   3.0     -5        -4.0          -9.5
5 2022-06-01  ZZ Ltd   1.6      3         3.5          -8.5
6 2022-07-01  ZZ Ltd   1.6      4         3.5          -8.5
7 2022-08-01  ZZ Ltd   4.0     12         0.0          -8.5
8 2022-09-01  ZZ Ltd   4.0     -4        -5.0          -8.5
9 2022-10-01  ZZ Ltd   4.0     -6        -5.0          -8.5
```

Explanation:

- create a new column `first` containing the starting `Rate` for each `Client`
- create a boolean column `rate_change` indicating the first row with a new `Rate` for each `Client`
- create a column `cs` containing 0 prior to the `Rate` change and 1 after it, with a -1 value for the first row of the new `Rate`
- put the average of `Price` for each unique (`Client`, `cs`) pair into a new dataframe `df2`
- add new columns `pre_change_avg` and `post_change_average` to the original df
- set `New Column` using these before and after the `Rate` change, and for the row of change use 0
- set `New Column 2` to be the difference between `pre_change_avg` and `post_change_average`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```py
# Part 1: `New Column`
grouped = df.groupby("Client")["Rate"].diff()
m, groups = grouped.fillna(0.0).eq(0.0), grouped.ne(0.0).cumsum()
df.loc[m, "New Column"] = df[m].groupby(groups)["Price"].transform("mean")

# Part 2: `New Column 2`
df = df.set_index(groups).join(
    df.groupby(groups).last().groupby("Client")["New Column"].diff()
    .rename("New Column 2").bfill().to_frame()
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

- `New Column`: First group `df` over `Client` and determine where `Rate` changes. Then build a mask `m` to exclude the first rows after a `Rate` change, and determine the relevant groups for further `.groupby`. To get `New Column`: group over `groups` and build the resp. means over `Price`, but only on `m`.
- `New Column 2`: Build a minimal temporary dataframe with the unique `groups` as index and the `New Column` diffs per `Client` as values, and then `.join` it on `df` on `groups`.

Result:

```
         Date  Client  Rate  Price  New Column  New Column 2
0  2022-06-01  XY Ltd   1.5      5         5.5          -9.5
1  2022-07-01  XY Ltd   1.5      6         5.5          -9.5
2  2022-08-01  XY Ltd   3.0     10         NaN          -9.5
3  2022-09-01  XY Ltd   3.0     -3        -4.0          -9.5
4  2022-10-01  XY Ltd   3.0     -5        -4.0          -9.5
5  2022-06-01  ZZ Inc   1.6      3         3.5          -8.5
6  2022-07-01  ZZ Inc   1.6      4         3.5          -8.5
7  2022-08-01  ZZ Inc   4.0     12         NaN          -8.5
8  2022-09-01  ZZ Inc   4.0     -4        -5.0          -8.5
9  2022-10-01  ZZ Inc   4.0     -6        -5.0          -8.5
```

Comment: Thanks for this Timus, the code works great with this fake data set. but, in my real data set I'm not sure why is not working, I think is because of Index issue maybe. when I tried to apply 3rd line of the code I was getting error  'ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels'. so, then I added a code before grouped:  'df=df.reset_index()' also I tried 'df=df.reset_index(drop=True)' but I'm getting incorrect numbers in both columns. I also add a code to sort by 'Date' because Dates were not sort ascending as this example df=df.sort_values(by='Date')

Comment: @rossjim Hm, sorting along `Date` and resetting the index before the code in the solution should work... Are the values in the `Date` column actually `datetime`s?

Comment: Yes Date column is datetime

Comment: @rossjim Then I have no idea. You could try to figure out a minimal sample that produces a wrong result and add it to the question (if possible).

Comment: I think the issue that I'm having is that some clients have multiple products on same Month and that's when gets messy, I tried to group by Client and product ID in Line1 and Line 4 but still not working.  @Timus    
Adding a sample data to the question

Comment: I resolved the "New Column" with below code. still trying to figure it out "New Column2"  `df=df.sort_values(by=['Prod ID','Client','Date'])` `grouped=df.groupby(['Prod ID','Client'])["Rate"].diff()` `m, groups=grouped.fillna(0.0).eq(0.0), grouped.ne(0.0).cumsum()`

Comment: Thanks for your help Timus, this is the code I ended up for the second part.  only issue I'm having is that when "Rate" don't change values in "New Column 2" should zero, but is dragging the value from previous record I believe  df=df.set_index(groups).join(df.groupby(groups).last().groupby(['Prod ID'])["New Column"].diff().rename("New Column2").bfill().to_frame()).reset_index(drop=True)